# UnicodeDecodeError in pandas `read_csv`

Tags: pandas, csv, encoding, character-encoding

I am working with [*Financial Statement and Notes Data Sets*](https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/financial-statement-and-notes-data-set.html). The following code works well before 2010q3:

```
num = pd.read_csv('../zipdata/extracted/num.tsv', sep="\t", encoding="us-ascii", low_memory=False)
```

However, the same code does not work for this file (I saved it in Google Drive):https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i4M_UIaDLeGmAYKr4jVD_Fp3JnvZWXUS/view?usp=sharing

I have tried to use `file -I num.tsv` to check the encoding. The result is `num.tsv: text/plain; charset=us-ascii`.

I also find that the column `dimh` is in hex format. So, I also tried

`num = pd.read_csv('../zipdata/extracted/num.tsv', sep="\t", encoding="us-ascii",low_memory=False, converters={"dimh": lambda x: int(x, 16)})`

Anyone can help on this issue?

Comment: I tried iso-8859-1. It works.